# Can ReachableAddresses be on separate lines?

Tags: configuration

Can ReachableAddresses be on separate lines? Like this:

```
ReachableAddresses accept *:80
ReachableAddresses accept *:443
```

Or does it have to fit into one? Like this:

```
ReachableAddresses accept *:443, accept *:80
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can be multiple lines.

The config option is a [LINELIST](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/tor-0.2.4.17-rc:/src/or/config.c#l354) type, just like ExitPolicy.